# Heroku Error Compiling CSS Asset

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my latest deploy to Heroku I'm getting this error:

```
Error compiling css asset
Rack:Timeout:RequestTimeoutException: Request waited 3ms, then ran for longer than 1500ms
/app/vendors/bundle/ruby/2.20/gems-sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/to_css.rba;67:in 'erase!"
```

I'm not quite sure what has caused the issue, but I've narrowed it down to a specific deploy where things were working before but were broken after. The only thing I changed were html files and changed the value of a sass variable in one of the stylesheets. I committed to git then deployed to Heroku. I realized then that my jQuery wasn't working on the page, so I then precompiled locally (as I usually do) and deployed . Now the application is throwing that error and exceeding it's available memory. Yet, everything works just fine in development. Anyone have any idea of what went wrong?

**EDIT:** I should add that the Rack timeout error is thrown by the rack-timeout gem which is designed to stop slow requests and log an error. So this isn't directly the issue, rather a result of an underlying problem that's prevented the page from responding within the allocated amount of time.

Here's the gemfile as requested:

```
    #Use Jasny Bootstrap extension for input mask
    gem 'jasny-bootstrap-rails'

    #Use for Blog tags
    gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'

    #Use Carrierwave for image upload, fog for AWS S3
    gem 'carrierwave'
    gem "fog-aws"
    gem "mini_magick"

    # Use bootstrap will-paginate for pagination styling
    gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

    #Use will paginate for pagination
    gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'

    #Use BetterLorem for seed text
    gem 'betterlorem', '~> 0.1.2'

    # Use date_validator gem to validate Event start & end times
    gem 'date_validator', '~> 0.9.0'

    # Use Bcrpyt for password encryption
    gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'

    #Use FontAwesome for icons
    gem "font-awesome-rails"

    # Use to obfuscate email addresses on site
    gem 'actionview-encoded_mail_to', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.7'

    # Use to show instagram feed
    gem 'instagram', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.6'

    #Use TinyMCE to edit html content in posts
    gem 'tinymce-rails'

    # Use Jquery-turbolinks to fix turbolink issue
    gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

    # Timesout request that take longer than 15 seconds
    gem "rack-timeout"

    #Breadcrumb navigation
    gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"

# Use Gibbon for Mailchimp API navigation
gem 'gibbon', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.4'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.3'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11'
  # Use for storing environmental variables
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Tracks memory usage of each gem
  gem 'derailed'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest', '~> 5.8', '>= 5.8.4'
  gem 'mini_backtrace', '~> 0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest', '~> 2.4', '>= 2.4.4'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.8'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Comment: Depending on the sice of the sass file, and the power of the Heroku machine, 1500ms may be not enough time for it to compile. Could you show us your Gemfile to see your production/development dependencies?

Comment: I added the gemfile above.

Comment: So i went ahead and extended the timeout time to 25 seconds and it worked and all  the functionality has returned. Do you think this is just a temporary fix?

Comment: 25 seconds is way too much for a timeout. Try a smaller value, like 5 or 10 seconds. Also, if this is a production application (instead of a testing app), you should hire a powerful machine, or try a more mature service, like AWS or Azure.

Anyways, try optimizing your assets as much as you can when you are working with this languages.